# An error on create a StoredProcedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create StoredProcedure like this :

```
USE [banktest]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdatePayment]    Script Date: 8/21/2015 8:22:00 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[UpdatePayment] @status nvarchar(50),@RefID nvarchar(50),@SaleReferenceId nvarchar(50),@paymentId int
AS
BEGIN
    update bankpayment set [status]=@status,RefID=@RefID,SaleReferenceId=@SaleReferenceId where paymentid=@paymentId
END
```

But I have an error like this [image]

I tried to change that name but It doesn't work .
What should i do?

Comment: The intellisense cache does not update when you run a `CREATE ...`, run the statement and see what happens/for a more detailed error.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
```

instead of

```
ALTER PROCEDURE
```

Follow [THIS LINK](http://dattatreysindol.com/2012/05/29/tips-n-tricks-t-sql-an-elegant-way-to-create-or-alter-stored-procedures-in-one-go-for-easy-maintenance/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error. Just the cache is not created for that object. Please compile and I am sure you wont get any error.